# Inverse Permutations from $S_7$

Tags: permutations, inverse

Would someone mind giving an explanation of how to find the inverse permutation of:

$(1 2 3 5 7)^{-1}$ in $S_7$?

I am not quite understanding how to do this.

Comment: Just reverse the elements inverse will be $(75321)$

Comment: The inverse of $(12357)^{-1}$ is obviously $(12357)$... Maybe you want its inverse instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply re-write the original permutation in reverse to get 
$$\text{inverse permutation} = \left(75321\right)$$

**Why is this true?**

As a permutation is a bijection, then it has an inverse which is also a bijection. The inverse merely undoes what the original function does. Thus if $i\sigma = j$  then its inverse $\sigma_{-1}$ maps $j$ to $i$.

To find the inverse of a permutation that is a cycle all we have to do is write the elements of the cycle in reverse order.

You can always check if your inverse is correct by multiplying your permutation with the inverse and verifying that $\sigma \sigma^{-1} = 1$

**Cycle v/s Matrix notation**

If $$\sigma = (12357) = \begin{pmatrix}
 1&2&3&5&7\\ 
 2&3&5&7&1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$\sigma^{-1} = (75321) = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&5&7\\
7&1&2&3&5
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Ok, so would that be the same for say a 2D permutation: (1 2 3 4 5 6 7, 5 4 3 6 7 2 1)^-1 = (1 2 3 4 5 6 7, (then what goes here)). I used commas to separate lines, didn't know how to write it as a two layer parentheses.

Comment: What is a 2D permutation? 

In the case that the permutation is a product of cycles we must reverse the order of the cycles as well as invert each cycle.

For permutations written as the product of disjoint cycles we need only invert each cycle. I think that should sufficiently answer any case you have now? :-)

Comment: Sorry, look up, was too slow in writing.

Comment: No, it would not be the case for that. 2D permutations are a slightly different notational beast. You can't just reverse the cycle. You'd need to write 75321 on the first line and then put what 7 maps to below manually, etc... for each element.

Comment: So for my example, the line 5 4 3 6 7 2 1 would just be reversed (1 2 7 6 3 4 5)? It seems too easy to be true.

Comment: Does my edit make it slightly clearer? :-)

Comment: Yea it does. Thats great. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25473/discussion-between-zain-patel-and-thecrownedpixel).